# Tinymce 4 duplicate div's when there are empty div's

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

This is my first post and I've been searching for a solution for this problem several weeks without any result. I hope you can help me!!!
I'm going to try to explain my problem:
I paste this code into the code editor

```
    <div class="cta">                                     
        <div class="recomendado">                         
            Te recomendamos                                         
            <div class="triangulo"></div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

And click in the OK button. If I click again in the code editor, the result is:

```
<div class="cta">
<div class="cta">
<div class="recomendado">Te recomendamos
<div class="triangulo"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is not posibble for my aplication and the html code is created by the client and is not possible to changed that.
In this few weeks, I see the problem are the empty div's. (this example is a short example of the real code).
Our version of tinymce is the 4.0.23 and this is my configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea.-dlpe-html",
            theme: "modern",
            forced_root_block: false,
            resize: false,
            height: 450,
            valid_children: "+h3[span|p|br],h2[span|p|br],h1[span|p|br],h4[span|p|br],h5[span|p|br],div[div|h3|h2|p],span[span|strong],p[div|p|span|strong]",
            //extended_valid_elements: "+h3[span|p|br],h2[span|p|br],h1[span|p|br],h4[span|p|br],h5[span|p|br],div[h3|p]",
            valid_elements: "* [ * ]",
            extended_valid_elements: "* [ * ]",  //the blanks are not in real code
            cleanup: false,

            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink link lists charmap print hr anchor pagebreak",
                "searchreplace visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime nonbreaking",
                "save table contextmenu directionality paste textcolor"
            ],
            toolbar: "undo redo | code | styleselect | bold italic forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | print | fullscreen", 
        });
```

Please, I'm desperated with this bug. Thanks in advance (and sorry for my poor english).

Comment: I edit. Trying to solve this, I installed the 3.5 version. I write the verify_html: false propierty and still not working. I'm need a solution for this version or for the other. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can solved this problem.

After downgrade the tinymce version to 3.5, I notice that one of the lines in the configuration code was failling.

If you delete the "div[div|h3|h2|p]" part, the error no appear.

Thanks